# Azure Blob to SQL Server Bulk Insert - Don't have file access rights

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert a flat file from Blob Storage to a SQL Server Database. Here is what I have done:

1. Created a secure connection to Azure Blob and SQL Server using the master access key on the overall storage account. The connection is pointed at the specific container the files get staged "load-to-sql".

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'XYZ' 

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ohhyeaa 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE' 
SECRET = 'access policy key from the entire container' 

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources) 
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage 
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage 
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'CONTAINERaccount.blob.core.windows.net/load-to-sql', CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential)
```

2. File is loaded into a container
3. Execute:

   ```
    BULK INSERT [dbo].file.csv
    FROM 'StagingFolder_DataToSQL/project/date/file.csv' 
    WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', 
    KEEPIDENTITY, DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage', batchsize = 300000)
   ```

This gives me the following error:

> Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot bulk load. The file
> "StagingFolder_DataToSQL///.csv" does not exist
> or you don't have file access rights.

I am the owner of the server and the specific database where data is getting loaded.

**Are there access settings that I need to define in the Azure portal to allow for the file to load?**

I have been successful with this process in a different Azure environment and it worked great. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `StagingFolder_DataToSQL///.csv` doesn't look like a valid file to me, and I think the problem is the "does not exist" part of the error message, not the "don't have file access rights" part.

Comment: the string got messed up the way I typed it in. I updated the code. Should make more sense now.

Comment: What did you do for your `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` statement?

Comment: 1st >> "CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'XYZ' ... 2nd >> CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ohhyeaa (next line) WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE' (next line) SECRET = 'access policy key from the entire container' ...... 3rd >>> IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources) ..(next line)..
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage ..(next line)..

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
   LOCATION = 'https://CONTAINERaccount.blob.core.windows.net/load-to-sql',
   CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential)

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76783034/edit) your question to include additional information, such as the code you used to create the data source. As you can see from the difficulty with your comment, comments are not the place to add blocks of code or useful formatting.

Comment: Updated the description. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot bulk load. The file "StagingFolder_DataToSQL///.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

The Cause of error is the **access token you are using it doesn't have read permission** on the object that should be loaded, or the **file path is incorrect/Dose not exist file path is Case sensitive**.

**Get Container scoped SAS token with appropriate permissions:**

[image]
**My SQL Code:**

```sql
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'strong_password' 

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ohhyeaa7 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'Container_scoped_SAS_token' 

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources) 
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage 
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage 
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'https://<Storage_Account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<Container_name>', CREDENTIAL= ohhyeaa7) 

BULK INSERT dbo.student
FROM 'stagged/sample/file3.csv'
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
KEEPIDENTITY, DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage', batchsize = 300000)
```

[image]